# Recent research regarding if the local group of galaxies will remain bound to the Virgo Cluster?

Tags: gravity, expansion, galaxy-cluster, local-group

The question of if the local group of galaxies will remain bound to the Virgo Cluster has been asked before ([Is the local group bound to the Virgo cluster?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/2276/is-the-local-group-bound-to-the-virgo-cluster)). I am wondering if there is any more recent research regarding this? I haven't found anything more recent than the 2002 paper mentioned in the post I linked above: https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0204249

This is a subject that I know very little about, so I'm looking for advice on how to get more informed about it. There is a comment on the aformentioned post that says, "The confusing part is that there seems to be a gravitationally bound Virgo cluster, of which we are not part, and a gravitationally unbound Virgo supercluster, of which we are part." Does current research suggest that we are permanently bound, or only temporarily?

This more recent post ([Time-frame regarding cosmic expansion and the bound state of the Virgo Cluster](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/28984/time-frame-regarding-cosmic-expansion-and-the-bound-state-of-the-virgo-cluster)), for example, claims that we may be bound gravitationally to the Virgo Cluster enough to resist cosmic expansion and asks for a timeframe for which we are inexorably bound, but the answer seems insufficient to justify this assumption.

Comment: I read that the entire Virgo cluster is heading to a bigger cluster called Great Attractor, so perhaps things will be bounds for eons to come. No references ergo just a short comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most recent paper I have found is Hoffman, Y., Lahav, O., Yepes, G., & Dover, Y. (2007). [The future of the local large scale structure: the roles of dark matter and dark energy](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1475-7516/2007/10/016/meta?casa_token=wETQjyywtBwAAAAA:SoEUJDDqvzEYNXUW_v3u_dM2SLZmh1aFquisRJNV_rF5cFPFk4vfpvLBuxjiPAuhEhs-yXV3wAA). Journal of Cosmology and Astroparticle Physics, 2007(10), 016. They also found that the Local Group gets separated.